# how to adjust n amount of divs inside a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following pen:

http://codepen.io/yisera/pen/eNprye

Which what it is trying to do is adjust many `div` elements around the main container. However, I would like to achieve this in a way where after certain amount of divs are placed in the same row, the others are pushed to the bottom so that there's enough space for each div and the content inside them to not be stacked like a mess. 
I have a paint drawing trying to show what I want to accomplish:

[image]

I want them to stretch as far as they need, having the same height (achieved when setting the main container as `display: flex;`) but how can I make it so that when there's enough `div` elements in the first row without the content being too cluttered, they go to a second row, like the picture above shows? I've been trying to do this, but so far, flex will only shring the other `div` elements and stack more right next to them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Too cluttered",,,doubtful if CSS can help with aesthetics. You'd probably have to make those value judgments for yourself and pick an appropriate value.

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Adobe Flex, not the CSS flexbox model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this sample a try:

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.note {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #3498db;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

PS: Find more about flex model here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This works, partially, I removed the wrap-reverse into just wrap.. But I have one more question.. Some of the div's content might be a bit bigger than the rest.. Is there a way to make so that if the content of a div is slightly bigger than that of the others, said div can take more space?

Comment: try "flex: 2" for those that should be bigger. Let me know it it helps